# Getting 3 level deep JSON values with Alamofire 5.0 in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

**Alamofire 5.0** for some reason did not provide me with pure JSON but gave me a variant of the json file structure. Screenshot below.

[image: json retreived]

I managed to retrieve the data from the json which is one or two levels deep, but for some reason the structore is different for other properties.

I managed to retreive the *temp* values which is inside the **main** object, but I am not able to get *description* from **weather** object.

This is my code - *name*, *temp* are ok, *description* from weather is not working.

[image: xcode swift code - alamofire request]

Comment: please post code not screenshots of code

Comment: There are a lot of [related questions about parsing openweathermap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+openweathermap)

Answer (score 1):

Weather is an array so you should get it like this:

```
if let weather = JSON["weather"] as? [[String: Any]],
   let firstWeather = weather.first {
    data.description = firstWeather["description"] as! String
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That's because weather is a JSON array, you should retrieve it like

```
weather[0]["description"]
```

Hope this helps